# BCP SQL Server not importing rows with "#" in them

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to import some data into SQL Server. The rows which have "#" in them are failing.
A sample error output:

@ Row 10, Column 10: String data, right truncation @#

10381   LILAS   3       12/12/1996      1/9/1997        12/13/1996      3       7.99    LILA-Supermercado       Carrera 52 con Ave. Bolívar #65-98 Llano Largoa Barquisimeto    Lara    3508    Venezuela       2016-09-20 08:07:37.8709        2016-09-20 08:08:03.038652      2017-01-23 13:59:47     dec15637255344e7159952f43539a4ce        0       2016-09-20 08:07:37     2016-09-20 08:07:37     2017-10-12 11:05:24     2017-10-12 11:05:24     9999-09-09 09:09:09     9999-09-09 09:09:09     9999-09-09 09:09:09     9999-09-09 09:09:09     true    false   I

I believe BCP is treating the part after the "#" as a comment and not reading it. I went through the documentation but I could not find a way to specify a comment enable/disable flag. Is there any way to fix this, except for changing the data ?

Comment: What is the column delimiter here?

Comment: I am using "\t" (tab) as column delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that SQL Server is misinterpreting it, as you mention, but as a temp table or procedure.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)....

> Prefix local temporary table names
>   with single number sign (#table_name),
>   and prefix global temporary table
>   names with a double number sign
>   (##table_name).

If you're able to control the output for the file you're importing, I would highly recommend delimiting with double quotes.

Comment: In the bcp documentation, I did not see quotes anywhere. Do double quotes work while using bcp ?

Comment: @VoodooChild I'm referring to the file you're using bcp to import. The delimited file. Can you encapsulate the fields in double quotes.